# select data from table which dont have row in another table

Tags: mysql, select, if-not-exists

I have 2 tables. First `"product" (id)`. Second - `"product_has_option_value" (product_id, option_value_id)`.

How can I get product `id`s which doesn't have some `option_value_id` (for example 10)? "product_has_option_value" has many to many relationships.

Ok. I think I found the solution:

```
select p.id 
from product p 
where p.id not in 
  (select distinct(product_id)
   from product_has_option_value 
   where option_value_id=543)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is called "anti-join" (or "anti-semijoin"). There are 3 main ways to do this kind of query in MySQL (and some more in other DBMS, that have implemented `EXCEPT` operator):

- `NOT IN` subquery (no need for `DISTINCT` here but you may need to add the check `AND pov.product_id IS NOT NULL` if that column is nullable):

  ```
  select p.id 
  from product as p 
  where p.id not in 
    ( select pov.product_id
      from product_has_option_value as pov 
      where pov.option_value_id = 543
        and pov.product_id is not null
    ) ;
  ```
- `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` check:

  ```
  select p.id 
  from product as p 
      left join  product_has_option_value as pov 
        on  pov.option_value_id = 543
        and pov.product_id = p.id
  where pov.product_id is null ;
  ```
- `NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery:

  ```
  select p.id 
  from product as p 
  where not exists 
    ( select 1
      from product_has_option_value as pov 
      where pov.option_value_id = 543
        and pov.product_id = p.id
    ) ;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_has_option_value ON product.id = product_has_option_value.product_id
WHERE product_has_option_value.product_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
But it's not I'm looking for.
I need to find product id which doesn't have some option_value_id. If this product doesn't have it - product_has_option_value doesnt contais row with this product_id-option_value_id at all.

Comment: This select does this job. Instead SELECT * use SELECT product.id

Comment: This does find all products that are not related to any option value. If you want the products that are not related to **a specific** option value, it needs adjustment of the `ON` clause (as in my answer).