# How to generated missing dates between date range that do not exist in the joined table in CockroachDB?

Tags: postgresql, date, cockroachdb

I have Table A and Table A which have

```
Table A
id, start_date, end_date

Table B
id, table_a_id, archive_date
```

I want to return the dates that are missing in Table B, the dates that are NOT in the range of table_a start_date and end_date

How can I do this in cockroachdb?

I have tried using generate_series but I get a unknown signature error, generate_series does not take (date, date, interval)

```
WITH date_series AS (
  SELECT generate_series(
    (SELECT w.export_start_date FROM table_a w WHERE w.id = 123),
    (SELECT w.export_end_date FROM table_a w WHERE w.id = 123),
    '1 day'::interval) AS missing_date
)
SELECT ds.missing_date
FROM date_series ds
LEFT JOIN table_b a ON a.table_a_id =  123
```

Comment: There is an infinite number of days. Please define "missing" more closely. Seems we need at least an outer frame. And show exact table definitions including data types and constraints. Ideally, minimal sample values and desired result.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AXGY-oca) are 4 solutions which work and (see performance analysis below) are mostly faster than a modified version (see first fiddle) of the (currently) accepted answer.

First I created the tables and populated them.

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
  id         INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  start_date DATE NOT NULL,
  end_date   DATE NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE b
(
  id           INT  NOT NULL, 
  table_a_id   INT  NOT NULL REFERENCES a (id),
  archive_date DATE NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT b_pk PRIMARY KEY (id, table_a_id, archive_date)
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES 
(1, '2024-01-01', '2024-01-05'),  -- 5 days in Jan, Feb & Mar
(2, '2024-02-01', '2024-02-05'),
(3, '2024-03-01', '2024-03-05');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO b VALUES
(1, 1, '2024-01-01'),
(2, 1, '2024-01-02'),
(3, 1, '2024-01-03'),
(4, 1, '2024-01-04'),     
-- (5, 1, '2024-01-05'),  -- Missing the 5th of Jan.

(1, 2, '2024-02-01'),
(2, 2, '2024-02-02'),
-- (3, 2, '2024-02-03'),  -- Missing the 3rd of Feb.
(4, 2, '2024-02-04'),   
(5, 2, '2024-02-05'),

-- (1, 3, '2024-03-01'),  -- Missing the 1st of Mar.
(2, 3, '2024-03-02'),
(3, 3, '2024-03-03'),  
(4, 3, '2024-03-04'),   
(5, 3, '2024-03-05');
```

The queries.

### `EXCEPT` query:

```
WITH date_series (id, all_dates) AS 
(
  SELECT 
  id,
  GENERATE_SERIES
  (
    a.start_date, a.end_date, '1 day'::interval
  ) AS all_dates
  FROM a
  WHERE a.id = 2  -- get rid of records as soon as possible (could be IN (1, 2...)
)
SELECT 
  ds.id,
  ds.all_dates::DATE
FROM
  date_series ds
EXCEPT
SELECT 
  b.table_a_id, b.archive_date
FROM
  b
WHERE b.table_a_id = 2
ORDER BY all_dates;
```

Result (correct):

```
id  all_dates
 2  2024-02-03
```

### `LEFT JOIN` query:

```
WITH dates (a_id, a_dat) AS
(
  SELECT
    a.id AS a_id,
    GENERATE_SERIES
    (
      a.start_date, a.end_date,  INTERVAL '1 DAY'
    ) 
  FROM 
    a
  WHERE a.id = 2
)
SELECT 
  d.a_id,
  d.a_dat::DATE AS a_date 
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN
  b
ON
  (d.a_id, d.a_dat) = (b.table_a_id, b.archive_date)
  WHERE b.table_a_id IS NULL
ORDER BY d.a_dat;
```

Result - same!

`NOT IN (SELECT...` query:

```
WITH dates (a_id, a_dat) AS
(
  SELECT
    a.id AS a_id,
    GENERATE_SERIES
    (
      a.start_date, a.end_date,  INTERVAL '1 DAY'
    ) 
  FROM 
    a
  WHERE a.id = 2
)
SELECT
  d.a_id, d.a_dat::DATE  -- won't implicitly CAST back, but does in the WHERE
FROM 
  dates d
WHERE (d.a_id, d.a_dat) NOT IN 
  (SELECT b.table_a_id, b.archive_date FROM b WHERE b.table_a_id = 2);
```

Again, same result!

And finally (thanks to @ypercube for [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/201740/34007))

### `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
WITH dates (a_id, a_dat) AS
(
  SELECT
    a.id AS a_id,
    GENERATE_SERIES
    (
      a.start_date, a.end_date,  INTERVAL '1 DAY'
    ) 
  FROM 
    a
  WHERE a.id = 2
)
SELECT
  d.a_id,
  d.a_dat::DATE
FROM 
  dates d
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM b
  WHERE b.table_a_id = 2
  AND b.archive_date = d.a_dat
)
ORDER BY d.a_id, d.a_dat;
```

### `Performance Analysis:`

Before running the tests, we do<sup>(*)</sup>:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

<sup>(*) See `enable_seqscan` note at the end of this answer</sup>

You can check the fiddle for details of the plans and performance<sup>(*)</sup> produced by `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)`, but I find that I seem to get a lot of variation in the times reported. This happens even if I use my laptop which has nothing else running on it (bar my browser), and so should be immune to load spikes, whereas we have no clue as to what's happening at any given moment on the dbfiddle.uk server!

Having said that, the queries `EXISTS`, `NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN` appear to produce the best results on average - but YMMV!

<sup>(*) See caveats below</sup>

### Caveat:

- Testing performance with a small number of records is fraught with difficulty, see my remarks about variation above.
- Use **your** hardware and realistic table sizes for **your** testing.

A note about `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;`:

- This doesn't actually disable sequential table scans, it just makes them very expensive - see discussion below.
- Do not do this on production systems, or at least don't do it globally. You could, if and only if you fully understand any consequences, do it on a case-by-case, query-by-query basis, but it's not to be recommended - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165932/470530) for some guidance on this. Today's query hints are tomorrow's bugs - use with caution.
- The reason I'm doing it here is to force the optimiser to choose the index over a sequential scan. Without `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;`, the very small sample tables here would cause the optimiser to automatically choose a sequential scan. With a large number of records on a proper test system, this should not be a problem.

From the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html):

```
enable_seqscan (boolean)
```

> Enables or disables the query planner's use of sequential scan plan
> types. **It is impossible to suppress sequential scans entirely**<sup>(*)</sup>, but
> turning this variable off discourages the planner from using one if
> there are other methods available. The default is on.

<sup>(*) Emphasis mine</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From the the list of supported functions in CockroachDB's docs, https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/functions-and-operators, it looks like `generate_series` doesn't have that function signature (this is similar to Postgres -- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html).

What they do have is the following:

```
generate_series(start: int, end: int) → int
generate_series(start: int, end: int, step: int) → int
generate_series(start: timestamp, end: timestamp, step: interval) → timestamp
generate_series(start: timestamptz, end: timestamptz, step: interval) → timestamptz
```

The latter two might be applicable to your use case - if you're fine with doing something like:

```
WITH date_series AS (
  SELECT generate_series(
    (SELECT w.export_start_date FROM table_a w WHERE w.id = 123)::timestamp,
    (SELECT w.export_end_date FROM table_a w WHERE w.id = 123)::timestamp,
    '1 day'::interval) AS missing_date
)
SELECT ds.missing_date::date
FROM date_series ds
LEFT JOIN table_b a ON a.table_a_id =  123
```

Hope this helps

(Edit: this was just to address the syntax error given in CRDB)